# Deleting file with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i'm having troble deleting a file from a Laravel Project.
The file is in the /storage/exports directory, it's an excel stored on the disk usingthe Laravel Excel library.
This is my code:

```
$path = $excel->store('xls', false, true)['full'];
...send the xls via mail....
Storage::delete($path);
```

When i check the existence of the file with file_exist i get true, so Laravel is able to read the file.
I've also checked the permission for the folder and i give all permissions on this folder using chmod 777
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: After using Laravel I've learned one thing... EASY became DIFFICULT

Comment: try using [File](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/133/deleting-a-file)

Comment: use "File" facade to manipulate files stored outside storage/app folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage driver already has an awareness of a root directory, so the $path must be relative, not full.  So if your file is in:
`/this/is/the/full/path.xls`, and the config `filesystems.disks.local.root` is set to `/this/is/the/full`, you're essentially having it look for a file in `/this/is/the/full/this/is/the/full/path.xls`.

You have two options.

1) Add a new driver to that config, and reference it directly:

```
'custom_location' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => '/some/other/root/path',
]
```

`Storage::driver('custom_location')->delete($relativePathFromRoot)`

2) Create a one-off:

```
$rootPath = '/some/other/root/path';
$client = Storage::createLocalDriver(['root' => $rootPath]);
$client->delete($relativePathFromRoot);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the file within `storage/app/exports`. The `Storage` class's default location to store files is `storage/app`.

It may be a good idea to instead of using the `Excel` class to store the file, to instead save the file using the Storage class: `Storage::put('exports/excelfile.xls', $fileContents);`

Comment: Thanks. In the end i've used the Claymore's suggestion but your idea is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using Laravel, you can use regular PHP functions.

```
unlink($path);
```